# How to use ImageSource in xaml

Tags: xml, xaml, imagesource

I want to give the Button an Image like this:

```
<Button Name="Close" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="513,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="15" Width="15" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="Minimize_Click">
     <Button.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="{DynamicResource  CloseImage}"/>
     </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

and this is in my ResourceDictionary:

```
<ImageSource  x:Key="CloseImage"><Image Source="../Resource/close-button.png"></Image></ImageSource>
```

But it says that I can't add somethin in ImageSource
(In German):

```
  Resources.xaml(7, 39): [MC3028] Einem Objekt vom Typ "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource" kann kein Inhalt hinzugefügt werden. Zeile 7 Position 39.
```

I have no idea how to make this because this also doesn't work:

```
<Button Name="Close" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="549,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="14" Width="14" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="Close_Click" >
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="../resource/close-button.png" TileMode="None"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

It says the recource can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

you can just make this:

```
<Button Name="Minimize"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="513,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="15" Width="15" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="Minimize_Click">
     <Button.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="resource\minimize-button.png"/>
     </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

but you have to add the recource in the csproj like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="resource/close-button.png" />
    <Resource Include="resource/minimize-button.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

("resource" is a folder in my project)